# how to prove that $F(x)+F(x+a)=b $ has two solutions where $F(x)=x^3 + \alpha^{341}x^{36}$ in $\mathbb{F_{2^{10}}}$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

The above mentioned is considered APN function , [A new family of APN quadrinomials](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/994.pdf). Using SageMath code, it is easily to compute the function
$$
x^3 +   \alpha^{341}x^{36} + (x+a)^3 +   \alpha^{341}(x+a)^{36}=b
$$
has two solutions  in $\mathbb{F_{2^{10}}}$ , where $a , b \in \mathbb{F_{2^{10}}}$ and $\alpha$  is a primitive element in $ \mathbb{F_{2^{10}}}$.

**Q. how to to prove the binomial polynomial has  two solutions from mathematical side?**

**SageMath code**

```
def test_apn_function():

    N = 10
    F = GF(2**N, name="a")

    p = []
    for x_i in range(0, 2**N):
        x = F.fetch_int(x_i)

        y = x**3 +   (F.gen()**341)*x**36

        p.append(y.integer_representation())
    print(differential_uniformity(p)) # y+y(x+a)=b
```

Comment: What are $a$, $b$ and $\alpha$?

Comment: the questions is edited for a , b and $\alpha$

Comment: If $x$ is a solution, then so is $x+a$. So if $a\neq0$ then solutions come in pairs. Of course if $a=0$ then
$$F(x)+F(x+a)=2F(x)=0.$$
So with $a=0$, there are no solutions if $b\neq0$, and $2^{10}$ solutions if $b=0$. So your claim is not true for all $a,b\in\Bbb{F}_{2^{10}}$. Do you have some particular $a$, $b$ and $\alpha$ in mind?

Comment: @Servaes Otherwise your comment is spot on. But the keyword APN does imply, as you suspected, that $a\neq0\neq b$. This type of a problem emerges naturally in certain applications to cryptography.

Comment: Surely the goal is to show that there are AT MOST two solutions. Given an $a\neq0$, every $x$ is a solution for some choice of $b$. As is then $x+a$. This implies that for some choices of $b$ there cannot be any solutions, because we run out of choices for $x$. In other words, please include standard assumptions about APN functions into the question.

Comment: Don't the authors prove their results in that article? It is unlikely (though not impossible) that people here would come up with a simpler proof. At least for the general case, some trick may settle the case of $\Bbb{F}_{2^{10}}$.

Comment: For the particular polynomial the authors seem to refer to [16], and article by Edel, Kyureghyan and Pott from 2006. Did you look it up?

Comment: if you mean the paper with title "A new APN function which is not equivalent to a power mapping"" , it does not have detailed derivation I can follow.  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.88.1454&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Ok.  Undoubtedly you noticed that on page 6 the authors say that they have a theoretical proof, but that is is quite involved and gives no insight. I haven't thought about it, but if they resort to a computer verification that may be quite telling. If I were in my prime, I would probably try. I still may just for the heck of it, but I'm not very optimistic :-)

Comment: The function `differential_uniformity` is not defined. So we do not have a piece of code that works. (This would maybe show which is the question by reverse engineering at least.) The comment for the line with it, `# y+y(x+a)=b` makes no sense for me, The question involves a "binomial polynomial" - which is this binomial polynomial? The question mentions a 14 pages paper as reference, itself not self-contained. Where is exactly the APN function which is the object of this question in this paper? A polynomial has no solutions (it has roots, or an equation has solutions). Please adjust.

Comment: Please make clear what is $\alpha$ in the question. Is it a specific "generator"? Or the question wants us to show mathematically / humanly something for each potential choice of an $\alpha$. And please show the own effort for the question - since the answer cannot use code, we want please to see the own trials without code, it is the way questions are accepted on this site.